# Visual C++ - enable optimizations and browse the optimized code

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

How I can compile my project with optimizations turned on and see what optimizations changed in my code.

For example:

My original code:

```
printf("Test: %d",52);
for (int empty=0;i<100000;i++) {
    //Nothing here
}
```

Now when I compile my code with optimzations ,I want to see: (I think it'll be like that)

```
printf("Test: 52");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't <del>optimize</del> modify the source code (what you've shown in your question), but the binary, which consists of asm instructions.

How you turn optimization on and off depends on the compiler, so you'll have to refer to its documentation.

**In MSVS**, you can choose this option from the top toolbar - look for `Debug` (un-optimized) vs `Release` (optimized). You can see the binary code by stepping through the code with the debugger, right click -> show dissasembly.

Your code, for example, generates:

#### Without optimizations:

```
    printf("Test: %d",52);
0097171E  mov         esi,esp  
00971720  push        34h  
00971722  push        offset string "Test: %d" (9788C8h)  
00971727  call        dword ptr [__imp__printf (97C3E0h)]  
0097172D  add         esp,8  
00971730  cmp         esi,esp  
00971732  call        @ILT+575(__RTC_CheckEsp) (971244h)  
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
00971737  mov         dword ptr [i],0  
0097173E  jmp         wmain+49h (971749h)  
00971740  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
00971743  add         eax,1  
00971746  mov         dword ptr [i],eax  
00971749  cmp         dword ptr [i],186A0h  
00971750  jge         wmain+54h (971754h)  
        //Nothing here
    }
00971752  jmp         wmain+40h (971740h)
```

#### With optimizations:

```
    printf("Test: %d",52);
013A1000  push        34h  
013A1002  push        offset string "Test: %d" (13A20F4h)  
013A1007  call        dword ptr [__imp__printf (13A209Ch)]  
013A100D  add         esp,8  
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
        //Nothing here
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391442/how-to-see-the-optimized-code-in-c GCC allow you to see the optimized code. I want something that works with VC++.

Comment: GCC does optimizations while creating the AST. I don't know how MSVC does it.

Comment: @MessyCode: VC++ does not have an option like that.  It's either the origional source or the final assembly.  A lot of optimizations cannot be reflected in C code, and so you're unable to see them anyway.

Comment: @MessyCode you see the optimized binary.

Comment: @MessyCode *I want something...* Demanding things on the internet isn't going to get you places.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: according to MessyCode's link, it can "give you an optimized file" (whatever that means)

Comment: @MooingDuck `and you'll get an optimised file. you cannot run the code but using that you can get an idea of optimization` that's found in the answer.

Comment: @MessyCode what type of file? Is it a `cpp` file? If it's not, the source code doesn't change - which is exactly what I stated in the answer. And I doubt it does. MSVS also has that option - you get either an optimized or un-optimized `.dll` or `.exe` file and you can see the code with the `show dissasembly` option.

Comment: @Drise Sorry ,I didn't mean like 'You must do it'. `I meant if you would to help me, Help me.` or something like that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `you cannot run the code but using that you can get an idea of optimization` I think it's code and not assembly. Sorry but I am not interested in assembly code ,because to need time to understanding it.

Comment: @MessyCode I doubt that's possible even for gcc, I'll believe it when I see it. The optmizer does micro-optimization, it doesn't do major logical changes to your code. In this case as you can see, it removes the `for` loop altogether because it has no side effects, but doesn't modify the `printf` call enough for you to see any changes in how it's called.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You a little not correct ,I tested code in those two compilers with optimizations turned on and I got better result in GCC.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But micro-optimization is not better because it can't change the assembly and reduce the number of functions to do something. Like you saw in your post. The calling to `printf` changed.

Comment: @MessyCode that **is** the micro-optimization, and it's not visible in code.